# An array initializer of length '10' is expected

Tags: c#

I am a student and I am trying to write C # code over two dimensional arrays, but constantly writes it gives an error"An array initializer of length '10' is expected". How to fix it?

```
using System;    
static class MatrixBasic
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Int32[,] m = new Int32[,] {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},{0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},{0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}};
        for (Int32 iRow = 0; iRow <= m.GetUpperBound(0); iRow += 1)
        {
            for (Int32 iCol = 0; iCol <= m.GetUpperBound(1); iCol +=1)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0}", m[iRow, iCol]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The inner arrays in the array must have the same length. The first one has 10 elements, so the second one is expected to have 10 elements as well, but it has 11 (same with all the following ones).

Comment: I'm assuming the problem is actually inversed and the first array should have an extra first element of `0` that's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CherryDT mentioned, this is because the first array has 10 and the rest have 11. To fix your issue, you will have to add an element to the first array:

```
static class MatrixBasic
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[,] m = new int[,] 
        { 
            { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, 
            { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        };

        for (int iRow = 0; iRow <= m.GetUpperBound(0); iRow += 1)
        {
            for (int iCol = 0; iCol <= m.GetUpperBound(1); iCol += 1)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0}", m[iRow, iCol]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```